# How to apply calendar style in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datepicker, calendar

I'm trying to apply calendar style , but it not applying .

```
<DatePicker Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" Background="Transparent"
            CalendarStyle="{StaticResource CalenderStyle1}"/>
```

Style

```
<Style x:Key="CalenderStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Calendar}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>

    <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Calendar}">
                <StackPanel x:Name="PART_Root" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <CalendarItem x:Name="PART_CalendarItem" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Style="{StaticResource CalendarItemStyle1}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Style was applied with UI . Is there any mistake in my code ? Why style was not applying ?

Comment: post the xaml code of CalendarItemStyle1

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove Background property from your `DatePicker` tag.
2. Add `BorderThickness` property either to `DatePicker` tag, or `Style`.